# Unexpected error in checking hadoop version

Tags: hadoop

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ hadoop -version

java version "1.8.0_20"

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_20-b26)

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.20-b23, mixed mode)
```

After running this command, I get this. Unable to crack the problem. Checked all the entries in `/.bashrc` file. Please help.

Comment: I don't see an error?

Comment: I think you might have messed the configuration for hadoop home and java home in .bashrc   file